# Disc IO for query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, explain

is there a way to tell how much data MongoDB is reading from disc and how much from cache for a query ?
I looked at the explain()-Function but did not find this kind of informations.

Thanks, Andre

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible per request, but you might want to give the [free MMS](https://mms.mongodb.com/learn-more) a try, which has quite some metrics. Together with the hardware monitoring provided by munin-node, you get a pretty good picture on what's going on on your MongoDB servers.